# Spring - creating bean from collection or map

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

Some time ago i read about creating beans in Spring and there is an exception in creating bean for collections and maps.
I mean to create a bean for collection or map, it is needed to create a wrapper class with for example a list as a field of this class

```
public class CollectionBean {

  private List<String> someList;

}
```

and then it can be used in dependency injection. 
I wonder why it cannot be inject without wrapper class?

Comment: The blog post I created can be useful - https://jstobigdata.com/spring/mapping-and-injecting-collections-in-spring/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can absolutely create beans that are collections:

```
public class CollectionsBean {

    @Autowired
    private List<String> nameList;

    public void printNameList() {
        System.out.println(nameList);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class CollectionConfig {

    @Bean
    public CollectionsBean getCollectionsBean() {
        return new CollectionsBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public List<String> nameList() {
        return Arrays.asList("John", "Adam", "Harry");
    }
}
```

What might be causing confusion is that Java drops the generic part of a type at compilation. So Spring can't look at an object at runtime and know whether it's a `List<String>` or a `List<Integer>` -- to Java and Spring, at runtime, it's just a `List`.

This means that type-based autowiring won't work, when there's more than one bean of type `List`.

One way to get around this is to create a wrapper class, as you have done. Another way is to use one of the many other ways of disambiguating autowiring -- for example by name.